# Can same variables be used both on Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I'm not a mobile developer and searching google didn't provide me with a definitive answer, so my question is:

Can you use the same variables, something like:

```
"Foo %1$d bar %2$s"
```

bot in Android and iOS?

Context: would like to use the same language file base.

Comment: Your question does not make sense to me. `Can you use the same variables "Foo %1$d bar %2$s" ? `. What exactly you want to do?

Comment: Are you developing in hybrid environment?

Comment: i'm asking if this works on both platforms, if you give this string with two params to a print method.

Comment: I dont know about iOS but it's working fine with **Android**.

Comment: Yeah, Android documentation seemed more clear about this.

Comment: @BobbyTables It will work on iOS too.